# Django access related model

Tags: django, django-models

theres's something I'm missing or don't understand, maybe a very basic concept.

I have two models Person and Student, related by a `OneToOneField` like this:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    person = models.OneToOneField(
        Person,
        on_delete = models.CASCADE,
    )
    # fields definition
```

Should't I be able to access Student from Person with `student_set`?

Like this, but I get de error as follows:

```
>>> from people.models import Person
>>> p = Person.objects.get(pk=6)
>>> p.student_set.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'student_set'
>>>
```

Thanks!

Comment: If it is oneToOneRelation then why do you expect set to be returned? Just person.student or student.person

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer you are looking for is literally in the term "One to One relationship", there is not set returned here but a direct relationship.
p.student is going to access the student object related the person

Comment: It's obvious now. I guess because english is not my first language I missed the meaning of 'set'.